# In htaccess, is a redirect of "/index.php?main_page=" to "" safe?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have migrated to a new PHP CMS that has redirects, but the old site used the convention...

```
/index.php?main_page=
```

frequently. Would it be possible to alter this in htaccess without risking issues, that for example might redirect the same code on the admin I might not be aware of?

Comment: Not easy to tell without knowing what CMS you use to use and what you're using now and without know how both work. I would say it really depends on what links your old CMS had what has been indexed by search engines, etc.

Comment: I didn't get what you asked, can you please rephrase it ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera he is afraid that one of the links left by his old CMS may lead to an admin page or something important that may compromise the security of the new CMS he is using.

Comment: @SheikhHeera well at least that's what I believe he is asking hehe.

Comment: @Prix, it's funny that you answered and I got motivated :P